# Optimal Indexing Strategy

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mysql-5.6, index-tuning

For the sake of discussion, please refer to the simplified structure of our ecommerce database below (running on **MySQL 5.6** using **InnoDB** engine). At this point in time, the **transactions** and the **transaction_items** table stand at approx. **11.5MM** and **15MM** rows/each. These 2 are also the tables used the most (daily) for recording new **transactions**/**transaction_items** and producing **summary**/**aggregate** reports for analytics.

**Problem:**
As of right now, we feel that (aside from the size of data in the tables) we have a lot of indexes that are taking up unnecessary space and could possibly be deleted or altered to be more efficient with disk usage. Below are a few examples:

| table | index_name | size_mb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| transactions | idx_txs_on_staff_id_location_id_created_at | 298 |
| transactions | idx_txs_on_staff_id_topic_id_created_at | 298 |
| transactions | idx_txs_on_location_id_topic_id_created_at | 254 |
| transactions | idx_txs_on_customer_id_created_at | 225 |
| transactions | idx_txs_on_session_id | 184 |

**Question:**
Focusing on the **transactions** table solely, how would you index the table optimally to perform **date range** based queries involving **one** or **more** of the **foreign key** columns along with the **is_void** column (which is the generally NULL)?

[image: Schema Structure]

Here are some examples of our existing queries:

```sql
SELECT 
 t.* 
FROM 
 transactions t 
WHERE 
 t.location_id IN (1,2,3) 
 AND t.created_at BETWEEN '2020-12-01 04:00:00' AND '2020-12-01 03:59:59' 
 AND t.is_void IS NULL;
```

```sql
SELECT
 t.* 
FROM
 transactions t 
WHERE 
 t.staff_id IN (1,2,3)
 AND t.created_at BETWEEN '2020-12-01 04:00:00' AND '2020-12-01 03:59:59' 
 AND t.is_void IS NULL;
```

```sql
SELECT
 t.location_id,
 t.topic_id,
 COUNT(t.id) AS topic_count
FROM
 transactions t 
WHERE 
 t.created_at BETWEEN '2020-12-01 04:00:00' AND '2020-12-01 03:59:59' 
 AND t.is_void IS NULL
GROUP BY
 t.location_id, 
 t.topic_id;
```

```sql
SELECT
 t.location_id,
 t.staff_id,
 COUNT(t.id) AS staff_txs
FROM
 transactions t 
WHERE 
 t.created_at BETWEEN '2020-12-01 04:00:00' AND '2020-12-01 03:59:59' 
 AND t.is_void IS NULL
GROUP BY
 t.location_id, 
 t.staff_id;
```

```sql
SELECT 
 t.* 
FROM 
 transactions t 
WHERE 
 t.customer_id = 23
 AND t.created_at BETWEEN '2020-07-01 04:00:00' AND NOW()
 AND t.is_void IS NULL
ORDER BY
 t.created_at DESC;
```

**Edit - 12/24/2020 @ 3:05PM EST**
Database: MySQL 5.6 using InnoDB Engine

Comment: Does your DBMS support partial indexes?

Comment: Hi Colin, I tried checking and I don't believe MySQL 5.6 supports partial indexes

Answer (score 0):

So tackling this in the simplest of ways, the common predicates I see across your example queries are `created_at` and `is_void`. So you should have an index composed of at least those two columns (and optimally in the order of most unique to least unique), so likely the first column in the index would be `created_at` and then the `is_void` column after.

From there you can decide if you want to make your indexes fully covering for each scenario you provided above, e.g. one index for `created_at`, `customer_id`, `is_void`; another index for `created_at`, `staff_id`, `is_void`, etc (notice again the fields are in order of uniqueness). Or if you want to just let the generic `created_at`, `is_void` index partially cover each scenario and then your queries will do an additional level of filtering.

By looking at the table schema for `transactions` it looks like you have 5 foreign keys, so it wouldn't be the end of the world to have an index catered to each foreign key in conjunction with the `created_at` and `is_void` fields (if applicable to your scenarios). Five indexes is reasonable. And you don't need to fully cover every use case, but it's generally a good idea to identify your top use cases and try to cover them as best as possible by using the predicates of those scenarios in your indexes.

It also looks like you frequently `SELECT` `location_id` so it would be a candidate as an `INCLUDE` to your indexes (where it's not the predicate of the index themselves). E.g. `CREATE INDEX idx_txs_on_created_at_is_void_includes_location_id ON transactions (created_at, is_void) INCLUDE (location_id)`

Depending on the database system you're using (which you should tag in your question) there might be other features you can leverage to improve your indexing as well, such as [**Partial (Filtered) Indexes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_index#:%7E:text=In%20databases%2C%20a%20partial%20index,large%2C%20and%20have%20extreme%20selectivity.) as Colin mentioned. Since it seems like your normal uses cases (based on the examples you gave) always filter on `is_void IS NULL` then that would make for a good candidate in a partial index.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will update my question to reflect the database as being MySQL 5.6 using InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(customer_id, is_void, location_id)
INDEX(customer_id, is_void, staff_id)
INDEX(customer_id, is_void, created_at)
INDEX(is_void, created_at, location_id, topic_id)
INDEX(is_void, created_at, location_id, staff_id)
```

The order of the columns in each `INDEX` is important.  The inclusion of `is_void` is important to performance; leaving it out is why your indexes did not help much.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in text format, not images, and not index names.

Other suggestions:

- Use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(id)`.
- Use `DECIMAL` for money, not `FLOAT`.
- Deleting unnecessary `INDEXes` saves some disk space, speeds up `INSERTs` only a little, and is generally a low priority.
- Similarly, a "partial index" would not be much better than a full index.  (Anyway, no version of MySQL has bothered to implement it.)
- Other queries may or may not use the indexes you have or the indexes I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few principles that should be guiding you here:

The Golden Rule of Indexing:

> When you have multiple columns in your index, you can access using the column in the index so long as you use equality predicates on all prior columns in the index

This means that you probably want your date columns to appear last in the index. You only use range predicates against them so if you had an index on `(created_at , location_id)` and you had a filter of `location_id = 1 and created_at between '2020-12-01 04:00:00' AND  NOW()` then you would be reading all of the index that covers `created_at between '2020-12-01 04:00:00' AND  NOW()`. If the index was `location_id, created_at` then you would also be able to use the `location_id` filter to reduce the amount of index you read. You can read more about this rule [here](https://ctandrewsayer.wordpress.com/2017/03/24/the-golden-rule-of-indexing/) (it's written using Oracle but the principle is the same for any BTree index).

The second principle is that if a filter doesn't reduce the amount of data in the table you visit sufficiently enough then it's probably not worth including in the index. E.g. if `is_void` is generally null then having an index that will filter on that isn't going to benefit you much.

So your general pattern should be:

`(foreign_key, created_at)`

If you upgrade your MySQL to at least version 8.0.13 then you will be able to benefit from [Index Skip Scans](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-skip-scan) - this will allow an index that leads on a column with only a few distinct values to be used to filter on the secondary column. If you only had a few `location_id` values then an index on `(location_id, created_at)` could be used for your search on just `created_at`. If you don't upgrade then you will probably want an index that just covers `created_at`.

Looking at your index names, it looks like you've combined several columns for your current indexes, e.g `idx_txs_on_staff_id_location_id_created_at`. In order to benefit from this index you would have to have equality filters on `staff_id` and `location_id`, I don't see that anywhere in your examples. Even if there were queries that used both, it's likely that one column provides better selectivity than the other - in fact looking at your data model, it seems that `location_id` is a property of `staff_id` anyway so it shouldn't reduce the amount of data visited anyway.

---

Ordering columns in a BTree index by uniqueness is an old concept that hasn't ever really had any standing.